# Any ideas how the "stickr" widget developed on www.stickr.com

Tags: php, jquery

www.stickr.com has these post-it kind of stickers which can be attached on any website, I wanted to know how are these widget developed? is it developed using JQuery any ideas?

but the main issue I dont want local storage .... I want that If I send this url to a friends he should be able to see the stickr notes on that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/building-persistant-sticky-notes-with-local-storage/

A cool way to do this

Comment: THANKS A TONN !!!!! THIS WAS MY 1ST QUESTION ON STACKOVERFLOW AND I GOT AN ANSWER IN 3 MINUTES, I WAS SEARCHING A SOLUTION SINCE LAST 30 DAYS.. THANKS AGAIN

Comment: No worries, glad to help. remember to click the tick next to the answer if it helps :)

Comment: But there is a problem here ... I dont want local storage I want that if I send this url to a friend he should be able to see the stickr notes

Comment: then your option would be incorporate this into a global database so everyones sticky's are saved in one location

Comment: do you have any tutorial link..so that I can have some idea... thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry i cant think of any specific tutorial links on this topic. But give it a go and post some code in a new question and people can guid you